# Non-pae plus unstable Intel display driver

Tags: 12.04, pae

I have three (Pentium M) laptops. They are all in a good physical state and work perfectly well, so I have no reason to stop using them  When I first attempted to update to 12.04 the installation failed, reporting that the processor did not support pae. This led me to ask the original version of this question. This did not solve my problem, the question was marked as 'asked before' and not answered. None of the 'asked before' answers solved my problem so I was left with laptops I could not update.

As I can't actually add my own answer to this question due to it being labelled as 'asked before' (even though this variation of the pae question had not been asked), so I will answer it by editing the question.

I did some research on the Pentium M and discovered that it **DOES** in fact support pae despite the installation not finding it. The solution to my problem was to use the 'forcepae' boot option. From 14.04 onwards I believe this problem has been fixed in the installation.

Comment: Turns out that my Pentium M system DOES support pae after all. I used forcepae boot option and all was good. 

Anyone else struggling to get old Pentium M systems current with Ubuntu should be made aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether your issue is due to an old kernel, or just the Intel drivers, but my laptop (HP Compaq NC6000 with a Pentium M and a Radeon 9600) does well with Ubuntu 12.10 and the non-pae drivers from [webtoms bazaar page](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~webtom/+junk/linux-image-i386-non-pae/changes). If your system is not usable (no console on ctrl-alt-f1), you could install Ubuntu 12.10 or 13.04 with the instructions from [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-1210-on-non-pae.html).

Comment: You may be able to install Lubuntu 12.10 [see here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/how-to-install-ubuntu-1204-on-non-pae.html).  But other than that I don't think any official *buntu release still supports non-PAE systems.

Comment: That Webupd8 page gives an instruction on how to change the kernel from the cd/usb installer to a non-pae build. So you CAN install Ubuntu 12.10/13.04, although not officially.

Comment: Thanks,

I'll try the Webupd8 route abd see how it goes.